# Access SQL - One field doesn't exist, at least one of other do exist

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to update Checkbox in table, If same ID in another table doesn't exist, but at least one of other fields do exist. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE TableA
       INNER JOIN TableB_
       ON TableB_Name=TableA.Name OR TableB.Surname=TableA.Surname
       AND NOT TableB.ID=TableA.ID
       SET TableA.Checkbox=True
```

This SQL is placed in load event of form. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: What I want to do -

```
TableA

ID    Name  Surname 
200   John  Mills

TableB

ID    Name  Surname
300   Jane  Mills
```

You notice that in both table there is a match in "Surname" field. I want Checkbox to be checked in this case, BUT ID MUST BE DIFFERENT.

In other words, I want to set Checkbox to True if there is a record with DIFFERENT ID, but one of the other fields are same.

Comment: What do you want to do? Please explain more cleary. What are you expecting? What is happening?

Comment: @user4759923 See my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS()` , your query checks if there is a record with another ID, it doesn't check if **ALL** records have other ID :

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.checkbox = true
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB
                 WHERE (TableB_Name=TableA.Name OR TableB.Surname=TableA.Surname)
                       AND TableB.ID=TableA.ID)
```

This will update the field to `true` only if a record with the same name/surname and ID doesn't exists.

If 1 record with different ID is enough, you can use `EXISTS()` on the same principal :

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.checkbox = true
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB
             WHERE (TableB_Name=TableA.Name OR TableB.Surname=TableA.Surname)
                   AND TableB.ID<>TableA.ID)
```

Maybe you meant a combination , a record with the same ID doesn't exists, but exists one with another ID.. Then :

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.checkbox = true
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB
                 WHERE (TableB_Name=TableA.Name OR TableB.Surname=TableA.Surname)
                       AND TableB.ID=TableA.ID)
 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB
            WHERE (TableB_Name=TableA.Name OR TableB.Surname=TableA.Surname)
                  AND TableB.ID<>TableA.ID)
```

Comment: see my edited answer, I'm not looking for records that not exist, but records that not exist with same ID as in TableB and have one of the field same as in TableB.

Comment: And thats what my first query does. @LuckyLuke82

Comment: Sorry @sagi, I haven't seen your second SQL, this works, thanks!!. First one not, second one.

Comment: sorry to say, but I fully tested now - IT doesn't work ! It works when one of the other fields are Null, but if both fields have values  - checkbox gets checked even If ID is same in both tables. Should I use your 3rd SQL suggestion  or what ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Yes, if what you need is what is said there. It combine the first two together :)

Comment: No, actually I don't need this, I tested now. What I need is what I edited in my question. Problem with your suggestion is when one of 2 other fields (not ID), have the same value as in different records - checkbox still gets checked. I hope you understand - I need to check only 1 record, and compare only 1 record, not matches in whole table.

Comment: I think there might be some problems with "<>" in Access. Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Access. It has to be some other solution.